# KOrganizer Misbehaving - Times Are Wrong and Events don't Appear

Tags: korganizer

I am trying to use KOrganizer but it misbehaves completely.

First of all when I create an event and specify a time for it, then after I press apply the hour changes automatically to 12 o clock every time.

Also I can only see events at the agenda section. They don't appear anywhere else.

It is the first time trying to use KOrganizer so I don't know if I am making any mistake. It seems weird to be that much broken.

Comment: You can also try asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net), [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), or [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/). But don't forget to mention the version of your OS and the version of KDE Plasma. You can get that information from KInfoCenter.